# How to simplify summation containing trignometric function?

Tags: trigonometry, summation, trigonometric-series

> Prove that 
>   $$2 \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{x}{b}\right)^n \frac{\sin A}{n} = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2bx \cos A}{b^2-x^2}\right)$$

I have tried to do by changing this into imaginary part of exponential function but can't proceed more..

Comment: You had "sinn" in the original question. I was not sure if this was supposed to be $\sin$ or $\sinh$. Please check that the edit is correct.

Comment: I was also not sure if it was supposed to be $\frac{\tan^{-1}(2bx\cos A)}{b^2-x^2}$ or $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2bx \cos A}{b^2-x^2}\right)$. Please check to see if this is correct also.

Comment: See [Mercator series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series).

Comment: I bet $\sin A$ should be something like $\sin(Ax)$.